# TFS 2010 – Each new branch inherits custom groups permissions from main trunk

Tags: permissions, branch, trunk

When branching from the main trunk in TFS2010 all the custom groups and permissions (as granted in the main trunk), are inherited by the newly created branch. This results in a fair amount of permissions that needs to be cleaned up in the new branch after creation. 
(Each branch is a complete copy of the trunk)

I am making use of a script (bunch of tf commands) to set all new permissions on each new branch. As a last resort I am considering expanding this permissions script to manage the cleanup of the unwanted trunk permissions.

I am however hoping to treat the cause and not the symptom.

Is there any way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://tfsbranchpermremoval.codeplex.com.

It involves writing a plugin for TFS and deploying it on the TFS app server. After deployment, no permissions from the Main trunk are inherited by any branches on branching actions.